# Setting file name as variable with pyodbc, then running program as executable in data storage program instead of through Python

Tags: python, executable, pyodbc

I have created a program that calls a specific data set from Microsoft Access and applies some small changes and then creates a csv file.

However, currently the program needs to have the file name manually inputted into the code. When I try to create a variable and input it when pyodbc asks for the file to be called, the program returns an error.

```
sql_query = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM BMDL_SFAM_Final', conn)
df = pd.DataFrame(sql_query)

# Creating the cursor that allows us to select data with pyodbc
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM BMDL_SFAM_Final')
```

My first question is; is there a way to set the file name to a variable at the start of the program, and then just call that variable each time the program asks for the file name? I have tried setting a variable and also tried using .format(), each time getting the same error:

pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '* BDML_SFAM_Final'. (-3100) (SQLExecDirectW)")

My next step is to create an executable that can be called in the program where I store data. I don't want to have to open my python program to input the file name. Is there a way to have the file name selected when I select the file in the data storage software? The data storage software is called Element.

Comment: In `SELECT * FROM BMDL_SFAM_Final`, BMDL_SFAM_Final is a *table* name, not a *file* name. The file name (e.g., my_file.accdb) is specified in the connection string (or DSN entry) as `DBQ=`

Comment: Yes, sorry query name not file is what I meant. Either way I am not able to set a variable as the query or the file (in the query selection or the connection string).

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my own question.

You set your variable to the value you need for your database, query etc.
Then when you call your variable in the connection string or the query selection string you surround the variable with quotations and plus signs:

**example: '+database+'**

My code looks like this.

```
database = "C:\Element\Temp\outCCT.mdb"
query = "BMDL_SFAM_Final"

    conn_str = (r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};'
                r'Server=(local);'
                r'DBQ='+database+'; ')
    conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)

except pyodbc.Error as e:
    print("Error in Connection", e)

# Reading the Query and putting it into a panda Database
sql_query = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM '+query+'', conn)
df = pd.DataFrame(sql_query)
```

I found this help from the microsoft website:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15#next-steps

Comment: Still am yet to find how to make my executable work in my laboratory information management system (LIMS)